# Checking Statement of Health (NAP) info on Linux using Dhcp and Radius

Tags: windows, dhcp, radius, freeradius

I have a Linux `DHCP` server and windows clients. I want my `DHCP` server to assign an IP address from a network let's say `10.6.3.0/255.255.255.128` if the client has it's firewall **enabled** or an IP address from a different network if the client has it's firewall **disabled** let's say `10.6.3.128/255.255.255.128`

It would be much better if I can assign IP addresses from more different networks like if the firewall is enabled `10.6.3.0/255.255.255.0`, and if it is disabled `10.6.4.0/255.255.255.0`

I know that SoH data is sent in dhcp request vendor specific options. I have enabled NAP service on my client. But when I analyze the traffic through wireshark I do not see any packets containing information about firewall status of the client.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It think it has to be requested by the DHCP server. I honestly can't remember how though. Check the Microsoft standards?

Or I can help you if you decide to go the 802.1X route and transport it in MSHCHAPv2